# How can multiply a value I enter in an excel cell by a constant number, with result on appearing on same cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet where I need to enter values in days in cells in one column, and automagically convert those to seconds. How can I do this?

For example, say I want to have values in column B reflected as seconds. So in B1 I type 1, press Enter, and now the value in B1 is 86400; in B2 I type 2, press Enter, B2 becomes 172800.

Clearer?

Comment: Automagically?  Need VBA.  2 other options:  _1:_  Use two columns - enter values in one column and have a formula in another column.  _2:_ Enter all your values in days.  Enter 86400 in another cell.  Copy that other cell.  Select your days and Paste special.  In the dialog, select `As values` AND `Multiply`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *automagically* convert any number typed into column D to seconds as a true time value then right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose `View Code`. When the VBE opens, paste the following into the pane on the right side titled something like *Book1 - Sheet1 (Code)*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Erreur
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim a As Range, ms As Boolean
        For Each a In Intersect(Target, Columns("A"))
            If IsNumeric(a.Value) Then
                If a.Value <> 0 Then
                    a.Offset(0, 1) = a.Value * 86400
                Else
                    a.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
                End If
            End If
        Next a
    End If
    GoTo Fìn
Erreur:
    Debug.Print Err
Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Tap `Alt+Q` to return to your worksheet and start *seconds as numbers* into column D.

I'm walking the integer or double typed into the cell back as first hours then minutes and finally seconds. I find this the best way to retain the accuranacy of any milliseconds in the value given Excel's [floating point precision](http://blogs.office.com/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/) significance of 15 digits.

**EDIT:**
Modified to more closely approximate the OP's edited question

Comment: I simplified your code to do what my edited post wants to do. However, how do I make it NOT display a number when there's no input in a certain cell in column D? The way it works now, if I type say "1" in D1, it changes to 86400, which is correct. However, if I delete the contents of D1, it will say 0. I want it to be blank?

Comment: @ChrisF - I'm still not sure whether you want to deal with typed zeroes and blank cells (tapping `Del`) the same way but perhaps this modification above will help you along.

Answer (score 1):

Without VBA you can use a formula column, similar to the following example:

[image]

That is, you complete the Days column, and entries in the Seconds column will take the values in the Days column and multiply them by 86000 (24 hours per day x 60 minutes per hour x 60 seconds per minute). This is probably the best way to do this, as you still maintain the original data set (Days).

With VBA you can tap into the *Change* procedure associated with the *Worksheet* object using something like:

```
Dim redo As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ChangedCell As Variant

If Target.Count = 1 Then
  For Each ChangedCell In Target
    If redo Then
      If (ChangedCell.Column = 2) And (ChangedCell.Row > 1) Then
        redo = False
        ChangedCell.Value = ChangedCell.Value * 86400 ' * 24 * 60 * 60
      End If
    Else
      redo = True
    End If
  Next
End If
End Sub
```

The above code cycles through each element within the `Target` range (all the cells that changed) and updates them using the same formula as mentioned previously (multiplying the call `.Value` with 86400) *only* if the cell is within a specific range. The specific range mentioned above are cells in Column 2 and Row > 1. It's to avoid any calculation outside this range. Also, since the *Change* procedure is executed with each change, you may run into recursively updating your sheet. For that, a Boolean `redo` is created to avoid recalculating any changes.

While using a VBA solution is great, you lose the original data set with this update, so I would advise against it.

Finally, you could use a Paste-Special method, where you copy the value 86400 (from anywhere on your sheet), then select the range you're interested in updating and Paste Special > Operation > Multiply:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I modified Jeeped code to meet my needs

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("D")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Erreur
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim d As Range
        For Each d In Intersect(Target, Columns("D"))
            If IsNumeric(d.Value) And d.Value > 0 Then
                ' Interested in a 8-hour day
                d.Value = d.Value * 3600 * 8
            Else
                d.Value = ""
            End If
        Next d
    End If
    GoTo Fìn
Erreur:
    Debug.Print Err
Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```